# nodejs newrelic throws Error: EACCES, open '/newrelic_agent.log'

Tags: node.js, newrelic

I just tried to get newrelic tracking on my node app working (http://newrelic.com/nodejs), however I get the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EACCES, open '/newrelic_agent.log'
```

According to newrelic node is logging to the same directory. However this seems to me that it is trying to log to the root directory?!

Manually creating the file in the server root works. However this isn't what I like to do. Is this a bug?

How can I set the log path?

Comment: try adding a dot before the slash:  './newrelic_agent.log'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your log path in your `newrelic.js` configuration file.

```
logging : {
  filepath : 'log_path_here'
}
```

Or

You can set the log path with an environment variable. You an use the `NEW_RELIC_LOG` environment variable.

Environment variables override settings made in the `newrelic.js` config file.

Comment: How do i set environment variables?

Comment: You can prefix the environment variable to the command you use to start your app. As an example (from the command line), `NEW_RELIC_LOG='log_path_here' node app.js`.

Comment: thx, is it also possible to define which newrelic config to use in the script? I have to servers in one folder lets say: server1.js and server2.js. Thus I'd like server1 to use newrelic1.js and server 2 use newrelic2.js?